# What format to use for storing graphs

Tags: python, graph, bulbs, tinkerpop

I am working on a project which involves working with graphs extracted from some other source. Currently we are using python's [networkx](http://networkx.lanl.gov/) module for analysing the graph.

I am now faced with the task of choosing a format for storing the graphs. Pickle seems to be a good choice for a purely python based solution. However we are now in the prototyping stage and there is a significant chance that we will have to switch to C++ for performance and scalability issues.

Therefore I'd like to have my graphs stored in a format widely supported by most graph libraries to minimise the hassle to be faced by future contributors in the project.

Could you please give me some suggestion regarding which format I should use?

Answer (score 4):

[TGF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trivial_Graph_Format) is your solution.

python example:

```
 #!/usr/bin/python

import fileinput, re

depends = {}
for line in fileinput.input():
    m = re.match('(.+):\s*(.*)',line) # find every depenency line of the form "<item>: <dependencies>"
    if m:
        item = m.group(1)
        dependency_list = m.group(2)
        print item,item # node definition

        if dependency_list: # there are dependencies
            depends[item] = dependency_list.split() # store the list into a dictionary for later

print "#" # end of node list, start of edge list

for item in depends:
    for dependency in depends[item]:
        print item,dependency # edge definition
```

Comment: Minimalist and beautiful. Thank you, sir.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sur being very relevant here, but wouldn't a [graph-based database](http://www.graph-database.org/implementations/) do the job?

You have a couple of option like [Neo4j](http://neo4j.org/) or [AllegroGraph](http://allegrograph.org/) for instance, and you will find easily a couple of bindings for python or any other language and most of the solution also provide a REST API anyway.

**note** that the [first link](http://www.graph-database.org/implementations/) I provided is not very up-to-date, there are now a lot more solutions, and API for Python are available even if it's written it's not on it. You could also have a look at [here](http://nosql-database.org/) (section Graph Databases).

**edit** I found that it could be interresting to have a look on this as well, it seems to be a suitable format for handling and storing graphes in either a JSON style or delimited text:

- [Geoff, The Easy Graph Format](http://geoff.nigelsmall.net/)

Also, you might want to take a look at here:

- [Bulbflow](http://bulbflow.com), a Python framework for graph databases which uses the querying language Gremlin and compatible with several DB systems
- [Gremlin, a graph traversal language](https://github.com/tinkerpop/gremlin/wiki) (see also [a presentation about Gremlin](http://www.slideshare.net/slidarko/gremlin-a-graphbased-programming-language-3876581), [the Bulb Gremlin API doc](http://bulbflow.com/docs/api/bulbs/gremlin/),  and [the gremlin plugin for neo4j](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/gremlin-plugin.html))

Comment: But for sure it isn't a very minimalistic solution :o)

Comment: Yes, Neo4j surely is a very relevant option here. Unfortunately, I have not found any in built function of Networkx to handler these databases, but I am looking into it.

Comment: @user506877, mmmh I don't know about networkx but at a first glance it doesn't seem to have a support for neo4j. Probably you could interface them quite easily with things like bulbflow ... I edited my answer with some few more details.